# Deploy image from EC2 Container Registry to Elastic Beanstalk credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

Given the setup of:

- Application developed locally and pushed to an [EC2 Container Registry](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) private registry
- An [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) environment set with a Docker host

In order to deploy my application, the Elastic Beanstalk [single container guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html) says to make a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file.

The Elastic Beanstalk guide [also says](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private) that to use images from (any) private repository, there needs to be a credentials file (with authentication token and email address) added to an S3 bucket.

Authentication [to the EC2 Container Registry](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html) involves querying for a token that the `docker login` command can use, ***but it's only valid for 12 hours***.

So, in theory, I can follow the Elastic Beanstalk guide, and use the `aws ecr get-login`, `docker login ...` command to get Docker to create the config file I need, convert that to a `.dockercfg` file and put it on S3.

If I then upload my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file as a new application version to Elastic Beanstalk, I can deploy it right then, if 12 hours haven't elapsed.

My concern is what happens after those 12 hours? If Elastic Beanstalk needs to auto-scale my application and spin up more instances, if it tries to use that S3-stored credential it will fail. Or if I realize I need to roll back to a previous version of my application, I can't just do that through the Elastic Beanstalk list of past application versions; I need to be on a machine with the AWS CLI installed and do the `aws ecr get-login`, `docker login ...`, upload to S3 dance again?

Is there a less fragile way to set up the authentication between Elastic Beanstalk and the EC2 Container Registry such that the 12-hour timeout isn't an issue?

Comment: seems to be possible with mutli docker beanstalk environment, but have not seen any documentation for single docker environments.

Comment: The Multi Container Elastic Beanstalk deployment uses the version 2 format of the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, but that version [also requires](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#docker-multicontainer-dockerrun-privaterepo) the `authentication` parameter point to a static, S3-hosted configuration file, so not sure how that solves the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at FAQs in ECR? check the question `Does Amazon ECR work with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?`.https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inlining the relevant [ECR FAQ answer](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/) here (added emphasis):

> All you need to do is specify the Amazon ECR repository in your Dockerrun.aws.json configuration and **attach the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly policy to your container instance role**.

Comment: What they don't tell you is that you also need to make sure that the ECR repository has a permission statement that allows your instance role (usually `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`) to access it.